# Like % with many values in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to write the like% query with too many values in sql ?

For example ,please see the table structure

```
Id Tid name
1  1   test
2  3   ram
3  10  felix

select * from table where Tid Like % 1,10 %
```

Also i am putting this value in a form , so post variable value like `$_POST['tid']=1,10`  so i am going to  will implement this like

```
select * from table where Tid Like % $_POST['tid'] %
```

Thank you .

Comment: Isn't it `select * from table where Tid IN (1,10)`?

Comment: Really thank you friends

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL offers `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(Tid, '1,10') > 0
```

Note that this will not use an index.  You can use `implode()` in php to use `in` instead, resulting in:

```
where tid in (1, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you . It is working . I don't have reputation to vote you now . But i will make  this as selected answer .